# Why do I get this error?

Tags: drush

I installed Drush with Composer and I get well the Drush version.
`drush cache-clear drush` works too, but `drush webform-libraries-make` returns me the following error.

> The drush command 'webform-libraries-make' could not be found.
>   Run `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the command file cache if you have installed new extensions.
>   Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.
>   Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
>
> - bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this case you can select another site with a working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for details.
> - connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be
>     wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See
>     http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.
>
> Drush was attempting to connect to:
>
> ```
> Drupal version         :  8.4.1
> Site URI               :  http://default
> Database driver        :  mysql
> Database hostname      :  127.0.0.1
> Database port          :  3306
> Database username      :  root
> Database name          :  fta
> PHP configuration      :  C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.ini
> PHP OS                 :  WINNT
> Drush script           :  C:/Users/s.guyennon/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
> Drush version          :  8.1.15
> Drush temp directory   :  C:\Users\SCF60~1.GUY\AppData\Local\Temp
> Drush configuration    :
> Drush alias files      :
> Drupal root            :  C:\wamp64\www\fta
> Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php
> Site path              :  sites/default
> Sync config path       :  sites/default/files/config_W7qQCKUh0SQJFJycX-Sl2-8Z4HSD33GszbC2yt0gl7Zi1KnhgtWfXBy4SYyOCWKImrhB7xVSpQ/sync
> ```

Comment: Is the Webform module (which provides the `webform-libraries-make` Drush command) enabled? Which version of the Webform module.

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250192/command-webform-libraries-download-is-not-defined for a related discussion.