# Command "webform-libraries-download" is not defined

Tags: webforms, drush

Suddenly the command in the title decided to stop working.

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
Command "webform-libraries-download" is not defined.
```

I'm on Drupal 8.4.2 and PHP 7.1.11.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Run `drush cc drush`, if that doesn't work make you sure have the most up to date version of Webform. I just ran `drush webform-libraries-download --help` with said version and got `Download third party libraries required by the Webform module. Aliases: wfld` so it's definitely working

Comment: Drush 9 is not yet supported. https://www.drupal.org/node/2916800